# Is there a way to define a conversion operator for any pointer type?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-keyword

I have this class:

```
class fileUnstructuredView {
private:
    void* view;
public:
    operator void*() {
        return view;
    }
};
```

and it can do this:

```
void* melon = vldf::fileUnstructuredView();
```

but it cant do that:

```
int* bambi = vldf::fileUnstructuredView();
//or
int* bambi = (int*)vldf::fileUnstructuredView();
```

instead i have to do

```
int* bambi = (int*)(void*)vldf::fileUnstructuredView();
```

or create another explicit type conversion operator for int*.

The point is, i want to easily convert the class into various pointer types including all the basic ones and some pod structure types. Is there a way to do that without creating a conversion operator for all of them? The closest thing to what I'm asking that I can think of is the ZeroMemory method that doesn't seem to have any types required for its arguments.

Comment: If you expose `void *` in any interface in C++, it is a big sign there is a problem with design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can have a conversion function template.

```
template <class T>
operator T*() {
    return static_cast<T*>(view);
}
```

Comment: That allows an implicit cast to `std::string*`, he only wants PODs and such

Comment: @MooingDuck That wasn't my interpretation of the question. I thought he meant that he didn't want to have to write a separate conversion operator for every type he wants to convert to.

Answer (score 2):

Use a template to allow conversions to all types, and then use `enable_if` to only allow it for POD and basic types.

```
class fileUnstructuredView {
private:
    void* view;
public:
    template<class T, 
        class enabled=typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value>::type
        >
    operator T*() { //implicit conversions, so I left the:
        return view; //pointer conversion warning
    }

    template<class T>
    T* explicit_cast() { //explicit cast, so we:
        return static_cast<T*>(view); //prevent the pointer conversion warning
    }
};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/774925a1fb3e49f5